# is it possible to use findAndUpdate and exclude certain fields?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection that I want to run findAndUpdate on, and I want to update the document with a document I have but exclude a specific field...is that possible?

for example, I have:

```
{
 "name": "john",
 "age": 30,
 "city": "new york"
}
```

and now I want to update it with:

```
{
 "name": "john",
 "age": 30,
}
```

using findAndUpdate, but leave "city" as it is...

I know its possible to use $set but I will need to specify all fields and its allot of fields so trying to avoid the clutter.

thanks

Comment: Why do you say that `$set` requires to specify all the fields?

Answer (score 0):

Using `$set` doesn't require to specify all the fields and is usable with `findAndModify`.

By example to update only `age`:

```
testrs0:PRIMARY> db.test.find({})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ee0adfda1f4463a43777b2e"), "name" : "john", "age" : 30, "city" : "new york" }

testrs0:PRIMARY> db.test.findAndModify({query: {name:'john'}, update:{$set:{age:31}}, new:true})
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ee0adfda1f4463a43777b2e"),
    "name" : "john",
    "age" : 31,
    "city" : "new york"
}

testrs0:PRIMARY> db.test.find({})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ee0adfda1f4463a43777b2e"), "name" : "john", "age" : 31, "city" : "new york" }
```